# How can I get ViewController from TabBarController on AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I use iOS5 storyboard, and my initial view controller is `TabBarController`, there are four relationships to view1 & view2 & view3 & view4, so, how can I get the view3's view controller?

I tried:

```
[[[[self.window.rootViewController navigationController] tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You said that your initial (root) view controller is a UITabBarController but you are referring to a view controller with a navigation controller with a tab bar controller. Are you getting mixed up in your view controller hierarchy?

edit:

if your root view controller is actually just a tab bar controller and you want to get the 3rd tab here is the code:

```
[[((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'viewControllers'

Comment: yes, it works. I am so stupid. UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

Answer (score 9):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Comment: While the most minimal answer ever, this is the simplest and best way to get the tabBarController. UITabBarController adds a category to UIViewController that returns a UITabBarController if the view is in one, or NULL if it isn't.

Comment: Is there any way to get the object(view controller) at a selected index?

Answer (score 7):

Try this way

In any view controller

```
 YourViewController *yourViewController= (YourViewController*)  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

this return your that view controller object.Cast it to your view controller and you are ready to use that.
run and Go

Comment: What would be the Swift 3 version of this answer?

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.0

```
let viewC = self?.tabBarController.viewControllers.first // will give single Navigation Controller on index 0
let viewC = self?.tabBarController?.viewControllers// will give array of Navigation Controller
```

Further you can check the Visible ViewController

```
if let nav = viewC as? UINavigationController {
   if nav.visibleViewController is YourViewControllerName{
        // Do Code
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   UIViewController *loginViewController=self.window.rootViewController;

   UITabBarController *controller=loginViewController.tabBarControllerObj;

   UIViewController *selectedController=controller.selectedViewController;
```

From this you will get selected view controller.

For getting all view controller just replace

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [controller viewControllers];
```