# show a view when push notification comes

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a chat application and it has a tab bar in storyboard as root view controller.

stack :

> tabbarController(rrot view controller)->view controller(4th index) -> tableViewController -> MyDestinationChatController

Now when the notification comes I want to open the `MyDestinationChatController` but when I do:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:myDestinationChatControllerObjVC animated:YES]
```

it does not push the view and just open my tabBarController with first index.

I have Googled the issue but not able to find a proper solution. The available solutions do not work and I am not able to understand how to handle it.

Any help is good.

Comment: you can use nsnotificationcenter for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Comment: @tnylee - thanks for the reply.  thats my last resort if any thing does not work out then i ll use that only.

Comment: @Neal You might have to get reference to the 4th ViewController. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688848/how-can-i-get-viewcontroller-from-tabbarcontroller-on-appdelegate

Comment: By definition a rootViewController has no parent or presenter, so `self.window.rootViewController.navigationController` will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

I would just present `MyDestinationChatController` modally.  If you need a way to cleanly dismiss the view controller, you can embed it in a navigation controller.

```
MyDestinationChatController *destVC = ...;

// Set properties as needed

UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destVC];
self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```